# unexpected Application Support path

Tags: objective-c, macos, path

I´m using the following two lines to get the proper path to the users Application Support folder which should be this: **/Users/username/Library/Application Support**

```
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Instead I´m getting this: **/Users/username/Library/Containers/jumbosoft.de.Egg-Breakfast/Data/Library/Application Support**

Obviously I doing something wrong. I just don´t see what???

Ronald

Comment: Is that with iOS or OS X?

Comment: Running the same code I'm getting "/Users/username/Library/Application Support".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app is running in the sandbox (and Apple is insistent that is not "doing something wrong" though some have debated it ;-)).

If you don't wish to be sandboxed turn off the setting in Xcode's project settings. Otherwise just make sure you don't hardwire any knowledge of *absolute* pathnames into your app and rely on API's such as the one you're already using.

Comment: Stupid me :) I just didn´t think of it. Thanks a lot.